# HTML table внутри form

Tags: html, вёрстка

Имеется сайт, где существует следующая ситуация:
есть страница, на странице есть

```
<form>
  <table class='formTable'>
    ...
  </table>
</form>
```

Внутри таблицы могут быть как всякие текстовые элементы, так и input-ы.

Что хочется сделать: хочется, чтобы можно было выставить какую максимальную ширину таблицы (какой-то аналог max-width), чтобы эта максимальная ширина ограничивала все текстовые элементы внутри таблицы.
НО, если в таблице есть input, у которого size выставлен таким образом, что он не влазит в таблицу, то нужно, чтобы таблица расширилась.

Текущая реализация: просто выставлен max-width для таблицы. В chrome все работает именно так, как хочется.

Проблема: это нифига не работает в safari. (код и картинки ниже).
По идее, max-width для table использовать нельзя. На что заменить, ума не приложу.

Вопрос, как сделать, чтобы это заработало как хочется?

Код и картинки:

Как это выглядит в Safari:
[image: Из-за input вылез и текст]

Дальше пример таблицы. Там стоит max-width для .formtable. Так вот в chrome он игнорируется, если input превышает размеры, а в safari он фиксируется жестко.

```css
.formtable {
  border: solid #aaa 1px;
  font-size: 13px;
  max-width: 600pt;
}
```

```html
<table class="formtable" style="width:500pt">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="1">
          <div class="helptext"><b>My Checkboxes.</b> tick</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="2"><label><input name="field1" value="1" type="checkbox">checkbox 1</label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="3"><label><input name="field1" value="2" type="checkbox">checkbox 2</label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="line"> </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="4">
          <div class="helptext"><b>My additional 1.</b> My additional 1 My additional 1 My additional 1My additional 1</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="5"><input type="text" size="120" value="" name="field2"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="line"> </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="line"> </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="8">
          <div class="helptext"><b>My additional 3 (*).</b> My additional 3</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="9"><label><input name="field4" value="4" type="radio">My additional 3</label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="10"><label><input name="field4" value="5" type="radio">My additional 33</label></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div class="line"> </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="11">
          <div class="helptext"><b>This is big input area.</b> The self-study lessons in this section are written and organised according to the levels of the Common European Framework of Reference for languages (CEFR). There are different types of texts and interactive exercises
            that practise the reading skills you need to do well in your studies, to get ahead at work and to communicate in English in your free time.</div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2">
        <div id="12"><textarea rows="6" cols="80" name="field5"></textarea></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Вы желаете добиться кроссбраузерности формы?

Comment: См по теме: https://habr.com/ru/post/331494/

Comment: Вполне закономерно будет использование max-width:100% для input либо другое значение в зависимости от ситуации. Вообще, хорошо, если ли б вы показали таблицу.

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Где код? Где скриншоты?

Comment: position: absolute - возможное решение.

Comment: Да, хочется добавить кроссбраузерность для форм.
Скрин таблицы и код добавил.